# Java Swing GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing

I've been learning Java Swing using GridBagLayout.

I have a main JFrame and add main JPanel, then I add subsequent JPanels/components to that main JPanel.

But anything I add **it always positions to the center** of the main panel (including while resize), which is not desired result.

Just a small snippet on the core code:

```
getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
getContentPane().add(panel);

GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;

JTextField nameField = new JTextField(10);
panel.add(nameField, gbc)
```

Any feedback would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the future, post a SSCCE when you have a problem. A small "snippet" of code generally doesn't help.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridbagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). The part on "weightx/weighty" will explain why this happens.

Comment: Sorry about the link, not sure what happened there. Glad you found the actual link. I updated my link as well.